# A bound for the exponent of the Schur multiplier of group G

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $M(G)$ be the Schur multiplier of $G$. Show that the exponent $\exp(G)$ of $G$ divides the product of the exponents $\exp(M(S_p))$ of the Sylow $p$-subgroups $S_p$ of $G$.

I tried to do ..., but I got stuck at ... Can you help me with...?

Comment: what is your question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: maybe, use transfer

Comment: It really depends on what results about Schur Multipliers you know already. For example do you know any results already that relate the $p$-part of $M(G)$ to $M(S_p)$?

Comment: note that every sylow p-subgroup of M(G) is isomorphism with some subgroup of M(Sp)

Comment: M(G) is abelian group and every abelian groups is direct sum of its sylow subgroups.

Comment: If you know that every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M(G)$ is isomorphic with a subgroup of $M(S_p)$, then then $M(G)$ is isomorphic to the direct product of all of its Sylow $p$-subgroups, and you should be able to solve the problem.